# Sending new/mutated data back to the page in the same POST request?

Tags: node.js, forms, reactjs, post, axios

Playing around with React and Node/Express what I have is a `form` with a `POST` request that sends some state information back to the server, on the server side I mutate/change the state and then send the state back in the same post without a `redirect()` or a page refresh.

```
router.post('/ProjectPost', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('postin up');
    const transform = req.body.incom += 'neewer'
    console.log(transform);
    res.json({backAtChew : transform});
})
```

Is this ok? Is it ideal? Does in only work here because of the small amount of data changes? Is this ok for scaling? Having the least amount of major page changes or refreshes is ideal for a SPA so this doesn't seem bad. In my actual application it will be major SQL calls or Oauthentication or API usage or what have you have you so I wanted to make sure before getting the idea that this was a way to go.

The calls to the server are made with `axios.js`

Comment: Ideally you won't have any page refreshes with a React SPA as everything is done via Ajax or some other means of async communication. Having an ajax post request handled on the server and returning some modified data is perfectly normal behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @xDreamCoding!